# How to load static resources from server-side javascript in CouchDB

Tags: javascript, couchdb

For CouchDB, I know that `show function` can generate HTMLs / Images / XML feed on the fly.

While in that case they have to be in the script itself and encoded (e.g. base 64 for image), [as in here](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/show.html)

What is the best way to load static resources which are attachments of design documents
 e.g. As simple as JSON, or  Images and process with server-side javascript?

The script file itself is an attachment in the design doc. The variable doc is not available.

Are there any way similar to node.js for it? or we use trick in context like  _show or _list to show the document with id: _design/ddoc ?

doing REST request inside that environment I believe is also not possible as XMLHttpRequest is also not available. Establishing DB connection is also not possible?

This supposed to be a simple question, I wonder I am missing something in couchDB?

Comment: [CouchDB docs](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Attachments) and [Nodejs http request](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback).

Comment: A bit to clarify, in my application couchDB is the only server - I try not to add node.js. and I try to fetch the static resources from server side javascript. can that HTTP API be used?

Answer (score 0):

In order to serve a website directly, you need to use [url rewrites](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Rewriting_urls). You'd rewrite `/` to got to one of your [show functions](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/show.html). to bootstrap your site with basic HTML and JS (embedded probably).

A lot of this work has been done already by [CouchApps](http://couchapp.org/page/index) (basic [tutorial here](http://couchapp.org/page/getting-started)). This is by far the easiest way to get started. This [seems](https://github.com/isaacs/npmjs.org) to be the way http://npmjs.org is served.

This isn't the place for a walkthrough, so hopefully this gives you enough information to get started.

If your site needs server-side logic (websockets for example), this solution won't work for you. All you get with a couch app is a database, HTML, CSS and Javascript.